# resonant frequency in a series resonant converter circuit

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, resonant-converter

I am designing a series resonant converter and wanted to convert 700 VDC to 100 VDC by using galvanic isolation. The switching frequency should be about 300 kHz (the output load is R = 1\$\Omega\$).

The question is what should be the resonant frequency? Is it better that the circuit works inductive or capacitive?

Please answer me in two cases. First case is when it is an open circuit, without any controlling circuit. The second case, when it is a closed loop, with controlling loop (for example controlling PWM of the MOSFETs).

Comment: So you want a 10 kW series resonant converter then?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes. It's true.

Comment: So exactly what level black belt are you now?  You may want to sit at the feet of Slobodan Cuk, the inventor of the Cuk converter.  And he will tell you plainly that having most of the resonance in the capacitance is best -- for efficiency, size, and cost.  Good luck, and warn those within a one mile radius before you turn it on for the first time ;-).